# How To Make a Mac Application/Installer (Java) Properly on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, jar, installation

I simply want to make a JAR file or APP file from my Windows machine that mac users can run and see a more professional application.

Most importantly, I want the menu bar title to say the program's NAME not the launcher package!  I find this really annoying since, when programming for Windows, you don't have to worry about that kind of crap.  Windows just shows the user whatever you name your JFrame when you create it.  Mac puts the full Launcher package name in the upper left-hand corner:

i.e.  com.blah.initial.Launcher

I've learned some from a Java Tutorial that covered bringing Java applications to Mac, but it didn't talk very much about how to do it from a Windows machine.

I am aware that an XML file is needed to tell the Mac program information.... but I'm not sure how to create and package all of it on Windows.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As seen in this [example](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/), a Mac [application bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_bundle) is just a directory tree with a name ending in `.app`. Once everything is laid out, just build your JAR and copy it to the destination directory, as shown in the `build` target of the project's [`build.xml`](http://robotchase.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/robotchase/trunk/build.xml?revision=66&view=markup).

> Do JWS applications show the application title in the task bar?

Mac OS X has both [menu bar and dock](http://www.apple.com/findouthow/mac/); the latter is similar to the task bar. In both,

- When double clicking an unadorned JAR, the fully qualified `Main-Class` name appears.
- When launched via [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start), the name is taken from the the [title](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#information) property.
- For an application bundle, the name is taken from the [`-Xdock:name`](http://robotchase.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/robotchase/trunk/Info.plist?revision=3&view=markup) property.

Comment: @Andrew: Good question; I've elaborated above.

Comment: Blast!  I'd have thought it was a no brainer to use the JNLP **title** element for the name in the task bar.  :(

Comment: Great stuff.  You've already mentioned JWS, so I'll just add..  If the app. has a GUI - launch it using JWS.

Comment: @trashgod So... I just make a folder in Windows with the extension ".app" ?

Comment: Well, you have to include the other stuff, too. As @Andrew helpfully points out, JWS will more easily solve your title problem. Of two dozen Java desktop applications I use, only two really need a bundle. Here's a related [example](http://home.roadrunner.com/~jbmatthews/java/macarach.html) that bundles a closed-source application.

Comment: @trashgod Eh... but see JWS goes through a process of starting the application through the JWS launcher and stuff, which I don't really want in this situation.  And besides, I have already designed my own auto-updating system that works quite nicely.  So, I would like to try this "bundling" technique.

Comment: *"JWS .. which I don't really want"*  Sure.  Do us a favor will you?  When you go to repeat this entire process with Ubuntu or RedHat or Fedora or Solaris or.., please mention in your question that you have ruled out using JWS, which is the obvious answer for deploying a GUI.

Comment: That's reasonable; just don't overlook the convenience of JWS. In a bundle, the `jar` and `Info.plist` are the essential variables.

Comment: @Andrew: Your point is well taken; I like how JWS always delivers the most recent version of one's application. The additional, platform-specific conveniences available to a bundle are a superset of those in the JAR(s) delivered via JWS. It's fairly easy to have `ant` update the bundle whenever the JAR is revised.

Comment: I don't doubt that the Mac. app. bundle offers things that JWS does not.  OTOH the only things I currently understand this deployment to require are 1) Set the app. title. 2) Update the Jars when needed.  JWS can do both (and much more).  But I do feel like I'm 'preaching to the converted' in telling you, and the OP has already made their decision. (shrugs..)

Comment: @Andrew: I recognize the usefulness of JWS in some situations, however, I can assure you I will not be looking to deploy bundles to any other platforms besides Windows and Mac.  Windows is easy... just use an exe wrapper.  Mac is the issue I am dealing with here.  The fact is MacOS and MSWindows, particularly the latter, by far dominate the PC market, thus being most important to adhere user friendliness to.  The rest will be perfectly fine with a good ol JAR file or JWS deployment setup specifically for them.

Comment: If you are using JWS as the fall-back for the systems where you do not have a better alternative like the app. bundle, this thread suddenly makes sense.  Best of luck with it, and I hope the users are so **un** impressed with the installer that they never wonder if it is Java (the sign of a great install is that the user misses it completely).

Comment: The Mac concept of application-bundle-as-filesystem-subtree dramatically simplifies the installer. Many are just a [`.dmg`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Disk_Image).

Comment: @trashgod I tried making an APP bundle following the exact instructions Sun put in one of their articles... and it didn't work.  Oh well.  JWS it is.  Unless.... I use JSmooth to wrap JARs in EXE files... is there a JarBundler for Windows someone whipped up out there perhaps?